# How to parsing this URL AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, parsing, url, get

Im novice in Angular. I have to get data from this url:

```
food?query=a&tags=91,92
```

and send request to API by this URL:

```
search?category-slug=food&query=a&tags[]=91,92
```

controller:

```
$scope.urlParse = {};
$scope.urlParse['expand'] = 'profile';
$scope.urlParse['category-slug'] = $location.pathname();
$scope.urlParse['query'] = $location.search('query');
$scope.urlParse['tags[]'] = $location.search('tags');

getSearchResults($scope.searchPath,$scope.urlParse);
```

But request request does not work
whats problem ?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Define "does not work". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely?

Comment: params object is likely wrong. request does not work =(

Comment: What request doesn't work? You didn't post any code making request, yet you expect someone to help you. We need details. What is `getSearchResults `?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice at angularjs too and i had the same problem.i solved it by using $routeParams provider of angularjs.
you just need to inject $routeParams in your controller and access the data from the URL by
`$scope.query = $routeParams.query;`
`$scope.tags = $routeParams.tags;`

and then add this values in your API request call.